# scrollToFixed : Fixed on bottom but only when enough space

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im am working with [jQuery plugin ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed).

I need to stick the address block on the bottom, but only when the window is enough height. 
Right now the address block **overlays the content**, when the window is not enough height.

[image: The addressblock should be fixed on the bottom]
[image: The addressblock should never cover content]

I need:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.address').scrollToFixed({
        bottom: 30,
        marginTop: 650
    });
});
```

But the combination of **bottom** and **marginTop** won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this without the plugin:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
            var height = $(window).height();
            if(height < 920){
                $('.address').css('position','fixed');
                $('.address').css('top','10px')
            }
            else if(height >= 920){
                $('.address').css('position','relative');
                $('.address').css('top','0px');
            }
        });
```

Comment: The scroll position matters too, not only the window height. Example: When I have "height >= 920" but the window is scrolled down, then the address-block need to be fixed on the bottom.

Comment: so the if's need to be exchanged with each other

Comment: maybe this is what your looking for too? `$(window).scrollTop() > 910`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example:
http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/

and look at this part:
     // previous summary up the page.

```
    var summaries = $('.summary');
    summaries.each(function(i) {
        var summary = $(summaries[i]);
        var next = summaries[i + 1];

        summary.scrollToFixed({
            marginTop: $('.header').outerHeight(true) + 10,
            limit: function() {
                var limit = 0;
                if (next) {
                    limit = $(next).offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true) - 10;
                } else {
                    limit = $('.footer').offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true) - 10;
                }
                return limit;
            },
            zIndex: 999
        });
```